Simple tile navigation system
I haven't done any programming in quite a bit of time, and I tried to make a program where a player navigates up, down, left and right on a grid.  I haven't used a tutorial for that, and I'm not really happy with the way I wrote it, especially the way I handled errors when the player tries to hit a wall and the way the grid is generated with 2d vector. can someone please look at this code and tell me how I could do it better? Any tips/tricks?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>

using std::string;

void print_vector(std::vector<std::vector<string>> v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << v[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

std::vector<int> find_player(std::vector<std::vector<string>> map) {
    std::vector<int> pos;

    for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].size(); j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == "X") {
                pos = { i, j };
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pos;
}

std::vector<std::vector<string>> create_map() {
    srand(time(0));

    std::vector<std::vector<string>> map = {
        { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", },
        { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", },
        { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", },
        { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", },
        { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", }
    };
    map[rand() % map.size()][rand() % map[0].size()] = "X";

    return map;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> player_pos;
    int player_x, player_y;
    char input = ' ';

    std::vector<std::vector<string>> map = create_map(); /*= */

    player_pos = find_player(map);
    player_y = player_pos[0];
    player_x = player_pos[1];

    while (true) {
        print_vector(map);
        input = _getch();

        switch (input) {
        case 'w':
            if (player_y == 0)
                break;
            else {
                map[player_y][player_x] = "0";
                player_y--;
                map[player_y][player_x] = "X";
                print_vector(map);
                break;
            }

        case 's':
            if (player_y == map.size() - 1)
                break;
            else {
                map[player_y][player_x] = "0";
                player_y++;
                map[player_y][player_x] = "X";
                print_vector(map);
                break;
            }

        case 'd':
            if (player_x == map.size() - 1)
                break;
            else {
                map[player_y][player_x] = "0";
                player_x++;
                map[player_y][player_x] = "X";
                print_vector(map);
                break;
            }

        case 'a':
            if (player_x == 0)
                break;
            else {
                map[player_y][player_x] = "0";
                player_x--;
                map[player_y][player_x] = "X";
                print_vector(map);
                break;
            }
        }

        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}


The input characters are not very mnemonic - I guess they are aimed at users with QWERTY layouts, but meaningless to the rest of us.


I haven't done any programming in quite a bit of time, and I tried to make a program where a player navigates up, down, left and right on a grid.

Congratulations on writing a working program! While there are lots of improvements that can be made, getting it to run is always the most important step.

I haven't used a tutorial for that, and I'm not really happy with the way I wrote it, especially the way I handled errors when the player tries to hit a wall and the way the grid is generated with 2d vector.

You learn a lot by just trying to implement something yourself first before looking at a tutorial. However, now that you've got something running, searching for tutorials and seeing how they do things compared to your program would be very informative. You can also search on Code Review itself for similar questions, and look at the answers they have gotten.

can someone please look at this code and tell me how I could do it better? Any tips/tricks?

Sure:
Add structure to your code and data
Your program consists of a bunch of regular functions that pass around vectors of vectors of strings. A great first step to improving your code is making this all a bit more structured, often literally by creating structs and classes. You have a map consisting of tiles, and you refer to tiles using their positions. So lets create these, and just start by filling them in with the data structures you were already using:
struct Tile {
    std::string contents;
};

struct Position {
    std::vector<int> coordinates;
};

struct Map {
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> tiles;
};

Note how this already simplifies a lot of your functions, for example, find_player() now looks like:
Position find_player(Map map) {
    …
}

The next step is to move functionality belonging to specific types into those structs as member functions. For example:
struct Map {
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> tiles;

    Map() { // constructor, replaces create_map()
        srand(time(0));
        tiles = {
            { "0", "0", … },
            …
        }
        map[…] = "X";
    }

    print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < tiles[i].size(); j++) {
                std::cout << tiles[i][j] << ' ';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    Position find_player() {
        Position pos;
        …
            pos = {{i, j}};
        …
        return pos;
    }
};

Now your main() will start to look like:
int main() {
    Map map;
    Position player_pos = map.find_player();

    while (true) {
        map.print();
        …
    }
}

But notice how main() modifies the contents of the map directly. You can still do that with the above structs, it will just look like:
map.tiles[player_y][player_x] = "X";

But this now requires main() to know that there is a tiles member variable and that it is a vector of vector of string. Ideally, you create a member function in map() that allows modifying the map without knowing how it is stored. For example:
struct Map {
    …
    void set_tile(Position pos, Tile contents) {
        tiles[pos.coordinates[1]][pos.coordinates[0]] = contents;
    }
    …
};

So that in main() you can just write:
map.set_tile(player_pos, "X");

Once you have that, you can change the way Map stores its tiles without having to change any code in main().
Make Position have x and y members
Now that you have Position and can pass those around as single objects, you can store the coordinates inside them as two different member variables:
struct Position {
    int x;
    int y;
};

This avoids having to convert between a vector of ints and x and y components.
Storing a map efficiently
You are right to be unhappy with the way you store the map contents. It's quite inefficient. First, the tile contents are either empty or contain the player. Instead of using a std::string for that, you can create an enum class:
enum class Tile {
    empty,
    player,
};

Then instead of passing strings you write code like:
map.set_tile(player_pos, Tile::player);

It makes printing the map a little bit harder though. The second issue is that vectors of vectors are also inefficient. It's better to create a one-dimensional vector, and use a little bit of math to figure out where in the vector to store a given tile:
struct Map {
    // Create constants for the width and height
    static constexpr std::size_t width = 5;
    static constexpr std::size_t height = 5;

    std::vector<Tile> tiles;
    
    Map() {
        tiles.assign(width * height, Tile::empty);
        Position player_pos = {rand() % width, rand() % height};
        set_tile(player_pos, Tile::player);
    }

    void set_tile(Position pos, Tile contents) {
        tiles[pos.x + pos.y * width] = contents;
    }
    …
};

If you can use C++23, then instead of doing this calculation by hand you can make use std::mdspan.
Keep track of the player position
The only thing your program does is move the player position, but interestingly you don't actually keep track of where the player is! Every time the player moves you have to find it and then change two tiles. Just keep player_pos around. In fact, in your program you can take it to the extreme and only store the player position:
struct Map {
    static constexpr std::size_t width = 5;
    static constexpr std::size_t height = 5;

    Position player_pos;

    Map() {
        player_pos = {rand() % width, rand() % height};
    }

    Position find_player() {
        return player_pos;
    }

    void set_player(Position pos) {
        player_pos = pos;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                char ch = (player_pos == Position{x, y}) ? 'X' : '0';
                std::cout << ch << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }        
    }
};

Of course I assume that if you want to turn this into a real game there will be other things on the map as well. But you can combine storing the map contents and the player position and get more efficient code.
Simplifying motion
You had to write a lot of code to handle just 4 movement directions, and most of it is duplicated code. Again, your spider senses are tingling with good reasons. Try to avoid code duplication as much as possible, as they are often a source of errors and a maintenance nightmare. First, do the bare minimum to get just the new position the player is trying to move to:
Position new_pos = player_pos;

switch (input) {
case 'w': new_pos.y--; break;
case 's': new_pos.y++; break;
case 'd': new_pos.x++; break;
case 'a': new_pos.x--; break;
}

Now try to check if the new position is valid and reject the move if not, or alternatively, just ensure the new position is valid. For example, you can use std::clamp() to do the latter:
new_pos = {std::clamp(new_pos.x, 0, Map::width  - 1),
           std::clamp(new_pos.y, 0, Map::height - 1)};

Don't use system() to clear the screen
Don't use system() to clear the screen: it is very inefficient (it starts a new shell, which then has to parse the command you pass it, which then starts yet another program which clears the screen, the latter which is written in C itself), it is not portable ("cls" only works on Windows, you need to use "clear" on most other operating system), and it is not even guaranteed that it does what you want (the system path and environment settings might be different on another computer, and "cls" might do something you didn't expect).
Since you are using conio.h, you can just call clrscr(). That still only works in Windows though. If it's not really necessary to clear the screen, I recommend not doing it at all.
Use C++'s random number generators
You are using C's srand() and rand() functions, which is good enough for your program, but in general those are quite bad. I strongly recommend you start using C++'s random number facilities.

Organize your #includes. Grouping libraries logically and sorting each subgroup alphabetically helps with readability and maintainability as the list grows.
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <conio.h>


Be careful with using-declarations in the global namespace. Namespaces exist to prevent collisions of symbols. You seem to be using it avoid typing the "std::" namespace prefix on std::string. Every time you type string, you are typing std:: prefixed to vector twice. If you want to shorten the amount of typing you need to do, use aliases in a scope.
struct Map {
    using cell_t = std::string;
    using row_t = std::vector<cell_t>;
    using map_t = std::vector<row_t>;
};

Parameter Passing. For "in" parameters, pass cheaply-copied types by-value and others by-reference-to-const. "Cheap" objects are usually not bigger than 2-3 words (e.g. double, pointers, references, std::pair<int, int>). For larger types (e.g. containers), they have a potential to be expensive to copy. You don't want to pay for that copy when the copy is unnecessary. It is cheaper to just pay for the redirection through a pointer or reference. In the case of a containers, there is typically an indirection to the underlying data anyway.
void print(const map_t& map) {...}


Prefer Range-Based for unless you need the indices to for something besides direct access.
for (const auto& row : v) {
    for (const auto& value : row) {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}


Use symbolic constants, not magic numbers. Unnamed constant values within expressions can be overlooked and/or hard to understand.
constexpr std::size_t height_v = 5;
constexpr std::size_t width_v = 5;

Data Structures. Pick the right data structure for the job. Each cell is type std::string. If it only holds one character, a char would do the job.
std::vector and std::string both have a constructor that will initialize the container with an element a provided number of times.
constexpr std::size_t height_v = 5;
constexpr std::size_t width_v = 5;

static_assert(height_v > 0 && width_v > 0, "Map dimensions must be positive.");

using cell_t = char;
constexpr cell_t ground_cell_v = '0';

// vector<vector<char>>
using row_vc_t = std::vector<cell_t>;
using map_vvc_t = std::vector<row_t>;

map_vvc_t map_vvc(height_v, row_vc_t(width_v, ground_cell_v));

// vector<string>
using row_s_t = std::basic_string<cell_t>;
using map_vs_t = std::vector<row_t>;

map_vs_t map_vs(height_v, row_s_t(width_v, ground_cell_v));

// array<array<char>> 
using row_ac_t = std::array<cell_t, width_v>;
using map_aac_t = std::array<row_t, height_v>;

map_aac_t map;
for (auto& row : map) {
    row.fill(ground_cell_v);
}

Avoid rand()/srand().
time(0) is implementation-defined. Most implementations will update time once every second. If multiple small maps are generated within a tick of second, the value from time(...) will be the same. This results in all generated maps within that tick being the same. The result of time(...) is a time_t, which is not guaranteed to be integral type (only required by POSIX).
srand(unsigned int) is expecting an unsigned int argument. Depending on what time(...) returns, a conversion could lead to a possible loss of data. You are limited to 32-bits of entropy with srand(...).
For rand(), the range of numbers it can generate are from 0 to RANDMAX. RANDMAX is implementation defined and is a minimum of 32767. rand() is typically implemented as a linear congruential generator (LCG), resulting in low quality random numbers being generated. At some point, the period of numbers generated will start repeating itself.
Specifically regarding modulo, when the input range isn't an exact multiple of the output range, there will be a bias toward the lower values in the output range.
In short, use <random>.
If you find the modular design to be cumbersome and/or don't want to work around some of the issues (Seeding Surprises, issues with std::random_device, Melissa O'Neil created a random_generator adapter to make <random> easier to use.
Keep in mind that <random>'s engines can be expensive to create. You don't want to constantly create new instances of them every time you need one. Distributions on the other hand are cheap to create.
randutils::mt19937_rng& get_rng() {
    thread_local randutils::mt19937_rng rng;
    return rng;
}

map_t create_map() {
    map_t map(height_v, row_t(width_v, ground_cell_v));
    
    auto& rng = get_rng();
    const auto x = rng.uniform(0UL, width_v - 1);
    const auto y = rng.uniform(0UL, height_v - 1)
    map[y][x]= player_cell_v;
    
    return map;
}


Don't declare variables until you have a value to initialize it with.
Single responsibility principle. create_map() creates the map and adds a player. You generate the player coordinates but you discard them. Instead, have one function create the map and have one function add a player.
map_t create_map() { ... }
coordinate_t get_spawn_pos(const map_t& map) { ... }
bool add_player(map_t& map, coordinate_t pos) { ... }
bool remove_player(map_t& map, coordinate_t pos) { ... }
void print(const map_t& map) { ... }

int main() {
    auto map = game::create_map();
    auto player_pos = game::get_spawn_pos(map);
    game::add_player(map, player_pos);

    while (true) {
        game::print(map);
        auto input = _getch();


case 's':
    if (player_y == map.size() - 1) { break; }
    // ...

case 'd':
    if (player_x == map.size() - 1) { break; }
    // ...

A Bug! What happens if the map dimensions are not square? In the 's' case, the y-index is correctly checked against the y-size. (map.size()). In the 'd' case, the x-index is also checked against the y-size (map.size()). If the map is tall, this is going to lead to an out-of-bounds access.
Avoid unnecessary condition nesting. else after break, continue, return, and goto, is unnecessary.
if (player_x == 0)
    break;

// player_x != 0 at this point
// ...
break;

Don't repeat yourself. Each case in your switch has duplicate code that writes '0' to the previous player location, writes 'X' to the updated player location, and prints the map. If these were the only key inputs you were going to support, extracting these repeated functions to happen before and after the switch would improve the maintainability.
Use the default case when switch-ing non-enumerated values. The default case either shouldn't execute and/or should notify something that an invalid case was switched on. For enumerated values, the compiler should warn you if you have a missing case.
const auto next_pos = [input](auto pos) {
    switch(input) {
        case 'w': pos.y++; break;
        case 's': pos.y--; break;
        case 'a': pos.x--; break;
        case 'd': pos.x++; break;
        default: assert(false); break;
    }
    return pos;
}(player.pos);

if (map.is_valid_player_pos(next_pos)) {
    map.unchecked_remove(player);
    player.pos = next_pos;
    map.unchecked_add(player);
}


AFAIK, compilers don't generally warn of missing enum case if you provide a default to handle the ones you didn't mention.  So better to write switch (input) { case 'w': ++pos.y; return pos; case 's': … … return pos; } assert(false); .  Though the assert() looks unfounded here, as input is supplied by user, and may well not be one of those values...
